# httpRequest inside a Promise

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I use the following code (simplified below for example's sake_ to get all users in my database, then access an external API which returns data which I want to save in the user's row in the database.

It does not seem to work... The user data is not saved. I'm new to Parse... so what am I doing wrong?

```
Parse.Cloud.job("updateToken", function(request, status) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    query.find().then(function(results) {

        var promises = [];

        _.each(results, function(user) {

                promises.push(function() {

                    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                      url: "http://www.example.com/",
                      success: function(httpResponse) {

                        user.set("authSave", httpResponse.text);
                        return user.save();

                      },
                      error: function(httpResponse) {
                        user.set("authSave", "testFail");
                        return user.save();
                      }
                    });
                });
        });

        Parse.Promise.when(promises);
    }).then(function(){
        status.success("YAY!");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the httpRequest is asynchronous, the functions that your passing to your array of promises will all be complete before the httpRequest's call their callbacks.

You want to use the promise returned from the httpRequest method and at that to the array instead.

Like this

```
Parse.Cloud.job("updateToken", function(request, status) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    query.find().then(function(results) {

        var promises = [];

        _.each(results, function(user) {

            promises.push(Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                    url: "http://www.example.com/"
                }).then(function(httpResponse) {
                    user.set("authSave", httpResponse.text);
                    return user.save();
                }, function(error) {
                    user.set("authSave", "testFail");
                    return user.save();
                })
            );
        });

        Parse.Promise.when(promises);
    }).then(function(){
        status.success("YAY!");
    });
});
```

I'm sorry if that's not perfect as I didn't test.
But it should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Did anyone test this in the end? This would improve the quality of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't take time to check, but he function handling query.find.then should return a promise.

Try with :

```
query.find.then(function(results) {

   ...

   return Parse.Promise.when(promises);

}).then (function(){
    status.success("YAY!");
});
```